# How to pass arguments

Tags: c

Hello I know the code is incomplete but I was trying to find the area of a triangle but I'm having difficulties finding the right function to put and which to return to get an output. I know I'll return the equation but I don't know what I should set area1 = to

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 double calculateArea(double, double, double, double, double, double);


int main () {
double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, area1, premiter1;
printf("Enter the coordinate planes");
scanf("%lf", &x1);
scanf("%lf", &y1);
scanf("%lf", &x2);
scanf("%lf", &y2);
scanf("%lf", &x3);
scanf("%lf", &y3);
area1 =
printf("Area : %lf", area1);
return 0;
}

double calculateArea() { 

return 

}
```

Comment: `(Base*Height)/2`? What is your question?

Comment: Mayne you need [Heron's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't completely understand your question but it seems this is what to tend to achieve :

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 double calculateArea(double, double, double, double, double, double);


int main () {
double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, area1, premiter1;
printf("Enter the coordinate planes");
scanf("%lf", &x1);
scanf("%lf", &y1);
scanf("%lf", &x2);
scanf("%lf", &y2);
scanf("%lf", &x3);
scanf("%lf", &y3);
area1 = calculateArea(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
printf("Area : %lf", area1);
return 0;
}

double calculateArea(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3) { 
double area;
//your logic here.
return area;

}
```

Similarly you can work with perimeter.

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem I was having was how to set up area1 and passing it